# Fullcalendar ignoring all options on initialization?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I'm using .NET with MVC 5.2.2 and bootstrap to develop a website. I want to use fullcalendar to display events (with no user interaction) on the site. After a lot of struggling to get fullcalendar to display, I managed to get it working. But it's ignoring everything I put in the initializer. I want to get rid of the Title, and leave just the calendar with maybe some of the controls. But all I get is the Title. I can't even add the events or callbacks.

Here's what I get so far:

[image: fullcalendar]

The scripts and css are in bundles, I'm trying to get it to work from the actual view, but at the moment they are in the layout page. Here's the rendered HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home Page - NNT</title>

    <link href="/Content/cerulean.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Content/multileveldd.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/Scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="/Scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.print.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="nnt-header">
        <img src="/images/logo-clear.png" class="nnt-logo" />
        <div class="nnt-caption">
            <span id="nnt-caption-title">NNT Caption Title</span><br />
            <span id="nnt-caption-body">NNT Caption Body</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">NNT</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Tasks <span class="badge">1,337</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Menu Item</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Theme &nbsp;&nbsp;<b class="glyphicon glyphicon-tint"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/default">Default</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/cerulean">Cerulean</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/cosmo">Cosmo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/cyborg">Cyborg</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/darkly">Darkly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/flatly">Flatly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/journal">Journal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/lumen">Lumen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/paper">Paper</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/readable">Readable</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/sandstone">Sandstone</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/simplex">Simplex</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/slate">Slate</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/spacelab">Spacelab</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/superhero">Superhero</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/united">United</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/Home/Index/yeti">Yeti</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Username &nbsp;&nbsp;<b class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#"><b class="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></b></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><b class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></b></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                    <li class="dropdown" role="presentation">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddm1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">DDM 1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ddm1">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item 1</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item 2</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item 3</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown" role="presentation">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddm2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">DDM 2<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ddm2">
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 5</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 6</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown" role="presentation">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddm3"" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">DDM 3<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ddm3">
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 7</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 8</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown" role="presentation">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddm4" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">DDM 4<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ddm4">
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 9</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown" role="presentation">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddm5" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">DDM 5<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ddm5">
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 10</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 11</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 12</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 13</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="dropdown" role="presentation">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="ddm6" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">DDM 6<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="ddm6">
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 14</a></li>
                                    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu Item 15</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="container body-content">
                    <div id="carousel-nnt" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="10000">
                        <!-- Indicators -->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#carousel-nnt" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-nnt" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-nnt" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                            <li data-target="#carousel-nnt" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                        </ol>

                        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <div class="nnt-slide">
                                    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                                    <div class="nnt-slide-content">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>In egestas lorem at erat ultrices, at consectetur lorem condimentum.</li>
                                            <li>Suspendisse faucibus augue at arcu rutrum, porta porta nunc dapibus.</li>
                                            <li>Nullam mattis lectus eu ultricies venenatis.</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="nnt-slide">
                                    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                                    <div class="nnt-slide-content">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>In egestas lorem at erat ultrices, at consectetur lorem condimentum.</li>
                                            <li>Suspendisse faucibus augue at arcu rutrum, porta porta nunc dapibus.</li>
                                            <li>Nullam mattis lectus eu ultricies venenatis.</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="nnt-slide">
                                    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                                    <div class="nnt-slide-content">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>In egestas lorem at erat ultrices, at consectetur lorem condimentum.</li>
                                            <li>Suspendisse faucibus augue at arcu rutrum, porta porta nunc dapibus.</li>
                                            <li>Nullam mattis lectus eu ultricies venenatis.</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="nnt-slide">
                                    <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                                    <div class="nnt-slide-content">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>In egestas lorem at erat ultrices, at consectetur lorem condimentum.</li>
                                            <li>Suspendisse faucibus augue at arcu rutrum, porta porta nunc dapibus.</li>
                                            <li>Nullam mattis lectus eu ultricies venenatis.</li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Controls -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-nnt" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-nnt" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h2>Calendar</h2>
                            <div id="calendar"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h2>Graph</h2>
                            <div id="graph"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                    <footer>
                        <p>&copy; 2014 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.plot($("#graph"), [[[0, 0], [1, 1]]], { yaxis: { max: 1 } });
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                dayClick: function () {
                    alert('a day has been clicked!');
                }
                // put your options and callbacks here
            })

        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my error was including the stylesheet "fullcalendar.print.css" without specifying the media attribute (I don't know how, since I'm using the bundles to apply stylesheets). This broke the buttons by overriding the default styles. I'm not sure how it broke the events for javascript or the callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this matters but try this:

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            alert('a day has been clicked!');
        }
        // put your options and callbacks here
    });
};
```

also might be helpful for those of us that don't use MS, to see the full html of the page that is rendeder (i.e. did the jquery etc scripts load correctly).
You said your calendar is now loading, but the dayClick isn't working?

Comment: Tried this, and it breaks the calendar so nothing is displayed. I've included the full html, though, maybe I ordered something wrong? Everything is loading as far as I can tell, I get some errors in the console, but I think those aren't from the calendar. A connection one (Pretty sure this is the VS debugger) and "no element found".

Comment: the errors can sometimes stop javascript execution. so i would hunt down the cause of those and fix them before trying to change anything else for the calendar. Far as i can see, it should at least load and display.

Comment: It seems the no element found is my problem. I don't know what's causing it though, it goes away when I remove most of the options and callbacks. I've managed to remove the title, but if I were to add the control buttons or a callback it breaks again.

Comment: try using jQuery 1.11.1 / jQuery UI 1.10.4, as per the documents, its only been tested with those versions. I'm using 1.11.2 successfully.

Comment: Hmm, I initially was using the included jQuery version, but I think it was conflicting with the updated version I have for bootstrap. Is it possible to use jQuery 1.11.1 for fullCalendar and the updated version for bootstrap on the same page?

Comment: you only need one version of jQuery... I use 1.11.2 and bootstrap 3.3.1 currently without issues.